# Question about Eric D. Black's Pound–Drever–Hall laser frequency stabilization paper

Tags: optics

My question is about equation 3.3 on page 4 of in [this article](http://elmer.tapir.caltech.edu/ph237/week13/BlackAJP01.pdf).  The equation gives the reflected power of a beam that is injected into a Fabry Perot cavity (the power of the beam leaving the same way it came in). The relevant terms of the equation are

$P_{ref}=\ldots 2 \sqrt{P_c P_s}\left\{Re[F(\omega) F^*(\omega+\Omega) - F^*(\omega)F(\omega-\Omega)] \cos (\Omega t) + Im[F(\omega) F^*(\omega+\Omega)-F^*(\omega)F(\omega-\Omega]\sin(\Omega t)\right\} \ldots $

Where $\omega$ is the frequency of a laser entering a fabry-perot cavity, $\Omega$ is the frequency at which the frequency of the laser is modulated before entering the cavity, $F$ is the ratio of the reflected field to the incident field (I don't think the form that $F$ takes is entirely relevant to this question, but it is given in equation 3.1 on the third page.)

He says that "We are interested in the two terms that are oscillating at the modulation frequency $\Omega$ because they *sample the phase of the reflected carrier*."  What does this mean, and why is it apparent from this equation?

edit: More specifically, what does the word "sample" mean here?

Comment: Doesn't the sentence (from the paper) preceding the one of interest answer your question?  *"The $\Omega$ terms arise from the interference between the carrier
and the sidebands, and the 2$\Omega$ terms come from the side-
bands interfering with each other."*

Comment: Perhaps.  I think my confusion is what he means by the word "sample" when he says that terms "sample the phase of the reflected carrier".

Comment: I agree that *sample* sounds a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you want to extrapolate the derivative of the reflected power, which is the error signal. This is implemented by adding a frequency $\Omega$ such that you can Taylor expand $F(\omega \pm \Omega)$ and get $\frac{\textrm{d}F}{\textrm{d}\omega}$.

So you want the term that contains $F(\omega \pm \Omega)$. The $2\Omega$ term comes from the interference of the sidebands so won't have $\omega$ so do the Taylor expansion.

Comment: What variable is $F(\omega \pm \Omega)$ expanded in relation to, and about what number is the expansion performed, in order to get the error signal from $F(\omega \pm \Omega)$?

Comment: With respect to $\omega$, so that the first order term goes as $\frac{dF}{d\omega}$ which is an antisymmetric function of $F$, the reflectance of the cavity. Antisymmetric means you can feed it to a PID loop. This is your error signal, the first derivative of $F$.

Comment: I'm wondering about the same question. This answer only works in the case where $\Omega$ is small compared to $\omega$. So why is the PDH Signal actually the Signal where $\Omega$ isn't small but still far apart from $\omega$? How does this work?